# Disk drive D: become invisible after Paging Files settings modification in Windows 7 SP1

Tags: windows-7

My laptop is running Windows 7 Ed Enterprise SP1. It has a physical disk of 250 GB subdivided into 2 primary partitions C: 121GB and D: 111 GB, not counting the small Windows 7 system partition usually masked. Two days ago, it was missing space on the C: drive and I decided to move the swap file to the D: drive. I fixed it size at 5964 MB as recommended by the system, and I disabled the automatic management of the paging file.

After restarting the system, I noticed that the D: disk no longer existed. I can see his partition in the Windows Disk Manager. But when I try to assign a letter to it, the operation fails because the current view of the disk manager console is not update. The system recommends to refreshing it or restarting the disk manager console, or restarting the computer completely. During these last two days, I performed these operations a dozen times without any success.

With the utility "EaseUS Partition Master 10.5", I can explore very well the data of the partition, but I get the error "The mounting of the volume failed" when I try to assign a letter to the partition.

Also with "MiniTool Partition 10.3", I can explore the data of the partition, but when I try to assign a letter to it, the utility informs me that the operation was successful, but the assigned letter disappears at the end of the operation.

I also watched with the MS-DOS DISKPART utility, but no volume is associated with this partition, so I cannot assign a letter to it.

Please, did anyone ever see this problem after changing the swap file settings in Windows 7? I deleted the Paging File, I recreated it on the drive C:, but the drive D: does not always appear, and I cannot always assign a letter to its partition with any of these 4 utilities.

I even looked at the HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoDrives key in the registry, but it is not set. Idem in HKCU.

What to do ? Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the solution to my problem. Here are the steps of the procedure followed for the resolution:

1. Start the "MiniTool Partition Wizard" utility (I personally have version 10.3)
2. Select the partition that is invisible at OS level (Disk 1 Partition 2)
3. Verify that MiniTool does not display this partition as hidden.
4. Click the right mouse button to open the context menu and choose the "Hide Partition" option from the list.
5. MiniTool adds the following command in the queue of pending operations

   1. Hide: (Disk 1 Partition 2)
6. Click the right mouse button again to open the context menu and choose the "Unhide Partition" option from the list.
7. MiniTool prompts you to select the letter to associate with the partition. Select D: in the list, in the dialog box that appears.
8. MiniTool adds the following second command in the queue of pending operations

   2. Unhide: (Disk 1 Partition 2)
             2. Unhide: (Disk 1 Partition 2)
             3. Set Letter: (D:)
9. Start the execution of the three pending operations by clicking on the "Apply" button in the MiniTool toolbar
10. At the end of the execution process, MiniTool asks you to restart the system to complete the requested operations. Click on the "Restart" button in the dialog box that appears.
11. During the reboot, a blue screen appears to indicate that the system configuration has changed. But since this is the first time you see this screen, turn off your computer and reboot it again as requested.
12. At the end of the boot operation, the D: drive appears again in Windows Explorer.